# error TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'null'

Tags: angular, typescript

I upgraded my Angular project and now I see that error peppered throughout. I've tried the strictNullsCheck = false in tsconfig, ! and ? but I can't seem to figure this one out.

```
  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<SongComponent>, @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: Song, public dialog: MatDialog, private fb: FormBuilder,
    public songsService: SongsService, public _snackBar: MatSnackBar, public _alertService: AlertService, public projectsService: ProjectsService,
    public authenticationService: AuthenticationService, private dataHandler: DataHandlerService) {
  }

  songEditForm = this.fb.group({
    title: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(128)]],
    projectId: [null, [Validators.required]],
    artist: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(128)]],
    album: [null, [Validators.maxLength(128)]],
    minutes: [null, [Validators.min(0), Validators.max(99)]],
    seconds: [null, [, Validators.min(0), Validators.max(59)]],
    songParts: [null, [Validators.maxLength(4000)]],
    timeSignature: [null, [Validators.maxLength(10)]],
    songKey: [null, [Validators.maxLength(10)]],
    bpm: [null, [, Validators.min(0), Validators.max(320)]],
    rating: [null, [, Validators.min(0), Validators.max(5)]],
    comfortLevel: [null, [, Validators.min(0), Validators.max(5)]],
    energyLevel: [null, [, Validators.min(0), Validators.max(11)]],
    notes: [null, [Validators.maxLength(512)]],
    genre: [null],
    isPublic: [null],
    isFavorite: [null],
    customSongProperties: this.fb.array([
      this.fb.group({
        id: [null],
        songId: [null],
        label: [null],
        value: [null]
      })
    ])
  });

 ngOnInit() {
    this.getArtists();
    this.filteredOptions = this.songEditForm.controls.artist.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(value => this._filter(value))
      );

    this.songEditForm.controls["title"].patchValue(this.data.title);
    this.songEditForm.controls["projectId"].patchValue(this.data.projectId);
    this.songEditForm.controls["artist"].patchValue(this.data.artist);
    this.songEditForm.controls["album"].patchValue(this.data.album);
    this.songEditForm.controls["minutes"].patchValue(this.data.minutes);
    this.songEditForm.controls["seconds"].patchValue(this.data.seconds);
    this.songEditForm.controls["songParts"].patchValue(this.data.songParts);
    this.songEditForm.controls["genre"].patchValue(this.data.genre);
    this.songEditForm.controls["timeSignature"].patchValue(this.data.timeSignature);
    this.songEditForm.controls["songKey"].patchValue(this.data.songKey);
    this.songEditForm.controls["bpm"].patchValue(this.data.bpm);
    this.songEditForm.controls["rating"].patchValue(this.data.rating);
    this.songEditForm.controls["comfortLevel"].patchValue(this.data.comfortLevel);
    this.songEditForm.controls["isFavorite"].patchValue(this.data.isFavorite);
    this.songEditForm.controls["isPublic"].patchValue(this.data.isPublic);
    this.songEditForm.controls["energyLevel"].patchValue(this.data.energyLevel);
    this.songEditForm.controls["notes"].patchValue(this.data.notes);  

    this.songEditForm.setControl('customSongProperties', this.setExistingCustomSongProperties(this.data.customSongProperties));
    this.getProjects();

  }
```

class definition:

```
import { CustomSongProperty } from "../settings/custom-song-properties/custom-song-property.model";

export class Song {
  id: number;
  projectId: number;
  title: string | null;
  artist: string | null;
  album: string | null;
  minutes: number | null;
  seconds: number | null;
  songParts: string | null;
  genre: string | null;
  timeSignature: string | null;
  songKey: string | null;
  bpm: number | null;
  rating: number | 0;
  comfortLevel: number | 0;
  isFavorite: boolean | false;
  isPublic: boolean | false;
  energyLevel: number | null;
  notes: string | null;
  disabled: boolean;
  sortOrder: number;
  created: Date;
  updated: Date;
  projectName: string | null;
  ownerFullName: string | null;
  projectRole: string | null;
  projectRoleId: number;
  customSongProperties: CustomSongProperty[] | [];
}


      <mat-card>
        <mat-form-field>
          <textarea matInput formControlName="notes" placeholder="notes" name="notes" rows="3" maxlength="512"></textarea>
          <mat-error></mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
      </mat-card>
```

Apologies as I'm not sure what else I can add to this post. I think patchValue is a method of FormBuilder / FormControl. One interesting thing is that the lines that are not failing are 'any' whereas the lines that are failing are 'null'.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please share the full type definitions in use here. This includes the full type of the `data` property present on the class. It is not possible to accurately answer your question without this information.

Comment: @amycodes updated. the data property comes from the song class posted.

Comment: I think it should work you tell TS that the type is `string | null`. You could achieve this by casting it, `null as string | null`, but there may be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

```
function processValue(value: null | string) {
  // Function logic
}

let inputValue: string = "Hello";
processValue(inputValue); // Valid
```

It's important to note that the appropriate solution depends on the context of your code and the intent behind using null as a type.